# Python tkinter update visuals of label with text and variable

Tags: python, tkinter

when i click the button in the tk window the label dosnt change. it is meant to change from money=0 to money=1. How can I update the visuals on the label?

Here is my code:

```
#imports
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

#varibles
money=0


#functions
def addmoney():
    global money
    money+=1
#window code
window=Tk()
#                              v-height in from top
window.geometry("450x600+735+240")
#                 w^  l^  ^width in from left

#widgtes
lm1=Label(window,height=2,width=20,text=("Money=",money))
btn1=Button(window,text=("Generate money!"),command=addmoney)

#positioning widgets
lm1.place(x=50,y=30,anchor=CENTER)
btn1.place(relx=0.5,y=200,anchor=CENTER)

#program code
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Function `addmoney()` must change the text on `lm1`. It won't change itself.

Comment: @DYZ how can I do that?

Comment: @Badda how can I update the visual of the label, money?

Comment: Read the documentation on `Label`.

Comment: @DYZ where is that? Can you link it?

Comment: Don't you know how to use google??? http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm

Comment: @DYZ thanks for the help

Comment: @DYZ I just tried:
     def addmoney():
     global money
     totmon=StringVar()
     money+=1
     totmon.set("Money=",money)
but comes up with the error: set() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a Label with a variable you're going to have to use `StringVar()` in your program. This is an example program I made:

```
from tkinter import *
money=0
global money
root=Tk()
display=StringVar() #create variable to be displayed by label
def get_money():
    global money
    money += 1 
    display.set("Money: "+str(money)) #combines "Money: " with variable and displays on label
money_label=Label(root,textvariable=display) #text_variable is used for displaying a StringVar()
money_label.pack()
money_button=Button(root,text="Get money",command=get_money) #button for getting money
money_button.pack()
root.mainloop() #updates tkinter window
```

I hope I understood your question correctly!